# If I'm modelling a circle to an exact size, how do I account for change in size with subsurf?

Tags: subdivision-surface

Basically, if I'm following plans to make something an it has exact measurements, is there like a ratio to use to know how much smaller the subsurf version of the circle will be? Or if there an addon that makes a surdivision surface go to the edges of a circle?

Comment: Why do you need Subdivision Surface? Can't you just add a circle, and increase its vert count?

Comment: I was going to suggest calculating the [inscribed radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_figure) of the circle. Like @EricXue said, the more vertices you start with, the closer the result

Comment: Get / Set the object dimensions after adding the subsurf.  eg  in python console `C.object.dimensions = (2, 2, 0)` to make subsurfed circle diameter 2.

Comment: I've never actually known about Python. I've been seeing scripts for blender for years, but I've never known what they are or how to use them. The inscribed radius is exactly what I'm going for, I just wish you could edit the inscribed radius when first making a circle.

Answer (score 1):

**Use object dimensions.**

Can use the object dimensions.  Eg add a plane or circle and set subsurf. Set the subsurf of view to render.

For example sake added default plane

In the python console

```
>>> # level 0 subsurf
>>> C.object.dimensions
Vector((2.0, 2.0, 0.0))

>>> # level 1
>>> C.object.dimensions
Vector((1.8333334922790527, 1.8333334922790527, 0.0))

>>> # level 2
>>> C.object.dimensions
Vector((1.8333334922790527, 1.8333334922790527, 0.0))
```

Now set to desired radius

```
>>> C.object.dimensions = (2, 2, 0)
>>>
```

Setting dimensions is altering the scale accordingly, values will be around `2 / 1.83333`

```
>>> C.object.scale
Vector((1.0909090042114258, 1.0909090042114258, 1.0))
```

Apply scale if need be, in which case the object with unit scale will be approx a 2 diameter circle when subsurf is 2.